# Why is there an Unicode at the end of pointer Array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, unicode, return

In the below Code,When the Value of n is even, while printing the array it prints with an unicode char,when value of n is odd, it prints without it.Can anybody say why is this happening?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    int d = 2;
    char *temp;
    temp = malloc(d * sizeof(char));

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int t = i;
        int t2 = d;

        while (t != 0)
        {
            temp[t2 - 1] = (t % 10) + '0';
            t2--;
            t = t / 10;
        }

        while (t2 != 0)
        {
            temp[t2 - 1] = '0';
            t2--;
        }

        printf("%s\n", temp);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Because you didn't null terminate your string. `malloc` doesn't initialize the content of the `temp` buffer. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323930/is-malloc-initializing-allocated-array-to-zero

Comment: ... and `malloc(d*sizeof(char))` allocates 2 byte buffer in which you can store strrings of a maximum length of 1. You need to allocate more memory.

Comment: Style note: you don't have to separately declare and initialize variables. You can just `char *temp = malloc(d);` The `sizeof(char)` is just `1`.

Comment: you don't even need to allocate memory dynamically in this case (and you're leaking memory)